# How are the edges of a polygon defined?

Tags: shapefile, vector, kml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are long lines in shapefiles to be considered geodesics or straight lines in the 2D latlong space?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25670/are-long-lines-in-shapefiles-to-be-considered-geodesics-or-straight-lines-in-the)

In various representations, such as shapefiles and kml, polygons are defined by their vertices. My question is what is the nature of the "line" which links two vertices? Is it a great circle arc? Is it whatever is a straight line in the current projection? If the latter, then the actual interior of the polygon in a function of the current projection, which seems undesirable.