# Which data formats can store Bézier curves?

Tags: database, file-formats

I've heard that ESRI .gdb can. Are there other databases or file formats that can as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30994/7424) by @Stephen Lead indicates that you are correct and Geodatabases can store true curves.  And here is [the page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m700000068000000) to show you how to create them in ArcGIS.

While not a GIS format, I know Adobe Illustrator can handle Bezier curves.
Also not a GIS format, but getting close, is Microstation DGN files.

It looks like [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineToCurve.html) can store curves.  But I'm not sure if these are Bézier curves.

If you have a look in the [documentation for FME's Readers and Writers](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#Welcome/Welcome.htm) you might be able to find more.  I did a search for "Bézier" and it only came up with the [Microstation](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#igds/Curves.htm) format.  However, if you search for "[Curve](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#search-curve)", you get more results. However, many of the results state that:

> "A curve segment may be a circular arc segment or a linear line segment."

Can I ask what you're using Bézier curves for?

Comment: Right now, just my general knowledge and future reference. Not too long ago, I was delineating alluvial fans for a class project and saving them in .shps. I was kind of annoyed to have my nice curves reduced to line segments when I went back to edit.

Comment: PostGIS curves are not Bezier, they're circular arcs.

Answer (score 3):

**Oracle and ArcSDE can**

When storing geometry in the database, ArcSDE populates the SDO_GEOMETRY value from an ArcSDE API object called SE_SHAPE. The **SE_SHAPE** object can contain simple and complex geometry that may include elevations, measures,* **CAD** data, annotation, and surface patches. The SDO_GEOMETRY data type supports a subset of these geometric properties. Because there is not a one-to-one mapping of the components in the SDO_GEOMETRY and the SE_SHAPE object, ArcSDE follows a set of rules when storing ArcSDE data in Oracle Spatial tables.

*Converts noncircular arcs (cubic spline, Bezier) to straight-edged linestrings. When the feature class is registered with the CAD entity mask (c), also store the curved representation in SE_ANNO_CAD_DATA.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/using_t1450550752.htm

Answer (score 3):

With Oracle 12c the SDO_GEOMETRY provides full support for generic curves (NURBs) which includes support for Bezier curves and cubic splines.